# PHPUnit gets wrong file when there is another folder with PHPUnit

Tags: cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-3.0

We have a CakePHP setup, with a saml on root folder, which is not included with composer, just included separately. Setup is like this

Project: /home/me/web/project
SamlFolder: /home/me/web/project/simplesaml

Now when I try to run tests on root folder of cakephp app with vendor/bin/phpunit , I get error due to that simplesaml having older version of phpunit. (PHPUnit 3.7.38 ). And with couple of deprecation errors

I tried excluding folder via phpunit.xml.dist from filters and testsuite but it keeps getting the subfolder first.

What can I do to completely ignore that directory by phpunit

Comment: I just always use a phar file, and I dont have any such problems: `php phpunit.phar`.

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do to completely ignore that directory by phpunit

If excluding files and folders doesn't work (works fine for me) for you for some reason then just pass the folder phpunit should use manually:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests
```

And it won't check other foldes outside of it.

Comment: already tried that but something weird is going on. When I do above like vendor/bin/phpunit ./tests/TestCase I still get PHPUnit 3.7.38  error. Weird thing is when I do vendor/bin/phpunit  it shows the correct version.

Comment: For now I installed phpunit globally and it solved it(or swept under the rug for today).